# How to filter rows based on conditioned explained?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe sorted by time:

```
  trID   event  time frameID    
  tID1    d      t1   1
  tID1    s      t2   1
  tID1    d      t3   1     
  tID1    d      t4   2      
  tID1    s      t5   2
  tID1    d      t6   1      
  tID1    s      t7   1
```

I want to get the sum of the difference of max(time) - min(time)
each time the frameID changes. For the Dataframe shown above, expected result would be :
    (t3-t1)  + (t7-t6)

There are multiple trIDs, and I need it for each trID

Comment: Do you think only rows with `frameID == 1` ?

Comment: I need the same number for every frameID which can be in range(1,25)

Comment: So need for `1` use `(t3-t1) + (t7-t6)` and for `2` - `t5-t4` ?

Comment: Yes, and I want these for each trID.  basically I want to group by trID, frameID and get that sum for each

Comment: How working my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
   trID event       time  frameID
0  tID1     d 2015-01-01        1
1  tID1     s 2015-01-02        1
2  tID1     d 2015-01-03        1
3  tID1     d 2015-01-04        2
4  tID1     s 2015-01-05        2
5  tID1     d 2015-01-06        1
6  tID1     s 2015-01-07        1

#create helper column for distinguish frameID with duplicates for unique groups
df['g'] = df['frameID'].ne(df['frameID'].shift()).cumsum()

#aggregate by 3 columns ang get difference
a = df.groupby(['trID','g','frameID'])['time'].agg(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
print (a)
trID  g  frameID
tID1  1  1         2 days
      2  2         1 days
      3  1         1 days
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

#sum by first and third level (trID, frameID) - get days
df1 = a.sum(level=[0,2]).dt.days.reset_index(name='SUM')
#similar get seconds if necessary
#df1 = a.sum(level=[0,2]).dt.total_seconds().reset_index(name='SUM')
print (df1)
   trID  frameID  SUM
0  tID1        1    3
1  tID1        2    1
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   trID event        time  frameID
0  tID1     d  2015-01-01        2
1  tID1     s  2015-01-02        2
2  tID1     d  2015-01-03        1
3  tID1     d  2015-01-04        1
4  tID2     s  2015-01-05        1
5  tID2     d  2015-01-06        1
6  tID1     s  2015-01-07        1
7  tID1     s  2015-01-08        1

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

#create 2 columns for groups
df[['g1','g2']] = df[['trID','frameID']].ne(df[['trID','frameID']].shift()).cumsum()

#add both new columns
a = df.groupby(['trID','g1','g2','frameID'])['time'].agg(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
print (a)
trID  g1  g2  frameID
tID1  1   1   2         1 days
          2   1         1 days
      3   2   1         1 days
tID2  2   2   1         1 days
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

#sum by first and fourth level (trID, frameID)
df1 = a.sum(level=[0,3]).dt.days.reset_index(name='SUM')
print (df1)
   trID  frameID  SUM
0  tID1        2    1
1  tID1        1    2
2  tID2        1    1
```

Comment: It should work if there are multiple clusters of frameID 1, for above case there are only 2 clusters, but there can be more number of times frameID 1 may appear. Also, could you please explain the last part ?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal - Sure. First, in solution is complicated multiple groups like 2 times group `1`, so is necessary helper column `g` for distingush it - first 1 group, then group 2 and last second 1 group (frameID). So after difference with max and min is duplicated `frameId` (because 2 times group 1), so need sum it. And by first and tird level (a.sum(level=[0,2])) - for `trID, frameID`. And because working with datetimes, use `dt.days` or `dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: Will it work if there are more than 2 groups of frameID, eg:   frID: 1 ,1 ,1 ,2 ,2 ,1, 1 ,3, 3 ,1, 1

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal - I think yes.

Comment: What should I do if I want to find the time difference between different groups of trackerID and frameID both combined, instead of just frameID as stated above.

Comment: I want the value of     `g`  to change every time there is a change in trackerID and frameID, instead of just frameID.